# Eclipse as editor for FileZilla. How do I configure it?

Tags: php, eclipse, filezilla

I've decided to switch from Netbeans IDE to Eclipse PDT. I use FileZilla to edit files on FTP. I wish to use Eclipse PDT as default file editor for FileZilla.

I opened up FileZilla, went to Edit > Settings > File Editing and put `/usr/bin/eclipse`under `User custom editor` radio, the way I had setup netbeans.

Now whenever I open any file for editing with FileZilla, a new instance of eclipse gets started. I want it to open as a new tab inside the already running instance of eclispe. I reckon there's some command line parameter that will get this done. But can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To accomplish this, you need to be using Eclipse 3.6 Helios or later, and you must add the `--launcher.openFile` switch when using it to open a file.  So, change your text editor in FileZilla to:

```
/usr/bin/eclipse --launcher.openFile
```

[More information is available on the Eclipse website.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature)

Comment: Eclipse 6.2 !?!

Comment: @KPL: Sorry about that!  I meant *3.6*.